# Counting regex strings in Yara

Tags: yara

I would like to know if we can count regex string in Yara?

I am not sure if Yara support this?

```
rule CountExample
{
    strings:
        $a = "dummy1"
        $b = /dummy\d+/

    condition:
        #a == 6 and #b > 10
}
```

There only match condition $b but #b can not count

Answer (score 0):

Using `#` with a regex string should still count.

Assuming these are the contents of the file:

**data1.txt**

```
dummy1
dummy2
dummy1
dummy1
dummy4
dummy1
dummy1
dummy8
dummy6
dummy1
dummy9
```

**data2.txt**

```
dummy1
dummy1
dummy2
dummy1
dummy1
dummy4
dummy1
dummy1
dummy8
dummy6
dummy1
dummy9
```

**data3.txt**

```
dummy1
dummy1
dummy1
dummy1
dummy1
dummy1
```

you rule will only match `data1.txt`.

Try playing with the data in [Cyberchef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=YARA_Rules(%27rule%20CountExample%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20strings:%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$a%20%3D%20%22dummy1%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$b%20%3D%20/dummy%5C%5Cd%2B/%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20condition:%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23a%20%3D%3D%206%20and%20%23b%20%3E%2010%5Cn%7D%27,false,true,false,false,false,false)&input=ZHVtbXkxCmR1bW15MgpkdW1teTEKZHVtbXkxCmR1bW15NApkdW1teTEKZHVtbXkxCmR1bW15OApkdW1teTYKZHVtbXkxCmR1bW15OQ)